# VueJS with Bootstrap icons for sort

Tags: vue.js

I'm sorting column data by click on the table header.

I have added the Bootstrap icons based on the v-show condition(s).

Earlier, the sorting worked on the click of the table header but now it should work on the click of icon which are not visible now to the right of 'Present' column.

Need help on this. The origin of issue is on Line 13 in HTML:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort" v-show="toolAttribute != activeColumn"></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L5p0ngdu/2/

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
results: {
  toolAttribute: [{attributeName: "Present", order: 1},{attributeName: "Present", order: 1},{attributeName: "Present", order: 1}],
  device: [
    {deviceName: "Device Name 1",
      info: [{value: true}, {value: false}, {value: true}]},
    {deviceName: "Device Name 2",
      info: [{value: false}, {value: false}, {value: false}]},
    {deviceName: "Device Name 3",
      info: [{value: true}, {value: true}, {value: true}]},
    {deviceName: "Device Name 4",
      info: [{value: false}, {value: true}, {value: false}]},
    {deviceName: "Device Name 5",
      info: [{value: true}, {value: true}, {value: true}]}
     ]
},
activeColumn: {},
currentSort:['deviceName'],
currentSortDir:'asc'
},
computed:{
    sortedResults:function() {
      return this.results.device.sort(function(a,b){
        let modifier = 1;
        if(this.currentSortDir === 'desc') modifier = -1;
        this.currentSort.forEach(x => {
        
           a = a[x];
           b = b[x];
        })
        
        if(a< b) return -1 * modifier;
        if(a > b) return 1 * modifier;
        return 0;
      }.bind(this));
    }
  },
  methods:{
  flasecond(index){
    let res = false
     this.results.device[index].info.forEach(info=> {
        if(!info.value) res = true
    })
      return res
  },
  sort:function(s) {
      //if s == current sort, reverse
      if(s.join('') === this.currentSort.join('')) {
        this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir==='asc'?'desc':'asc';
      }
      this.currentSort = s;
    },
}
})
```

```css
.falseclass{
  background:red;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="app">
<table >
 <tr>
 <th rowspan="2" @click="sort(['deviceName'])">Device Info</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th v-for="(toolAttribute, index) in results.toolAttribute" :key="index" @click="activeColumn = toolAttribute" :class="{active: toolAttribute == activeColumn}">{{toolAttribute.attributeName}}
 <span @click="sort(['info', index, 'value']); toolAttribute.order = toolAttribute.order * (-1)" :class="toolAttribute.order > 0 ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'" v-show="toolAttribute == activeColumn"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort" v-show="toolAttribute != activeColumn"></span></th>
 </tr>
 <tr v-for="(device, index) in sortedResults"  >
  <td :class="{'falseclass' : flasecond(index)}">{{ device.deviceName }}</td>
  <td v-for="info in device.info" :class="{'falseclass' : !info.value}">{{info.value}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

i have made some changes to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/thanseeh/tqy93meL/13/

```
<head>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="app">
<table >
 <tr>
 <th rowspan="2" @click="sort(['deviceName'])">Device Info</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th v-for="(toolAttribute, index) in results.toolAttribute" :key="index" @click="activeColumn = toolAttribute" :class="{active: toolAttribute == activeColumn}">{{toolAttribute.attributeName}}
 <span @click="sort(['info', index, 'value']); toolAttribute.order = toolAttribute.order * (-1)" :class="toolAttribute.order > 0 ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'" v-show="toolAttribute == activeColumn"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort" v-show="toolAttribute != activeColumn"></span></th>
 </tr>
 <tr v-for="(device, index) in sortedResults"  >
  <td :class="{'falseclass' : flasecond(index)}">{{ device.deviceName }}</td>
  <td v-for="info in device.info" :class="{'falseclass' : !info.value}">{{info.value}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your jsfiddle I see that you are using Bootstrap 4. When Bootstrap migrated to v4 the Glyphicons icon font has been dropped. I'd suggest you to take a look at one of these free alternatives:

- [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/start)
- [Octicons](https://octicons.github.com/)